# how to insert more than one value in table cell in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In following table there can be more than one list on particular date. So For list column there can be more than one list for given date.

I am able to insert more than one value in single cell **but it shift the row in which I inserted more than one value**, Please look at [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mhenmqcg/6/).

Example: Table

**Date**...............**List**

12/1/2016 ....     python, angularjs

13/1/2016.....   java, html

**data:**

```
$scope.todolists = [{
    date: '12/1/2016',
    list: {python, angularjs}
}, {
    date: '13/1/2016',
    list: {java, html}
}];
```

**view:**

```
 <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="todolist in todolists" >
        <td>{{todolist.date}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="list in todolist">{{subject}}</td>                                         
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I tried `ng-repeat` inside `ng-repeat` but it is not working. So my question is how to insert more than one value in single cell in table.

Comment: don't put the `ng-repeat` on the `td`, put a `span` in the `td` and put the repeat on that `span`.

Comment: also, it's generally not recommended to include a demo link with code significantly different from the code in the question body, since people may try to answer the question using the demo code.  Others reviewing the question later may not realize the code differences and have trouble following the question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your references are wrong.

```
 <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="todolist in todolists" >
        <td>{{todolist.date}}</td>
       <td ng-repeat="list in todolist.list">{{list}}</td>                                         
     </tr>  
 </tbody>
```

or, preferably,

```
 <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="todolist in todolists" >
        <td>{{todolist.date}}</td>
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="list in todolist.list">
                  {{list + ($last ? "" : ", ") }}
            </span>                                         
        </td>
     </tr>  
 </tbody>
```

Comment: thank for providing your answer, I tried but it is not working properly. have a look at demo http://jsfiddle.net/mhenmqcg/6/  Here Last row is shift. I updated question please see it.

Comment: @geeks, See the part version of my answer.  Instead of ng-repeat in the `<td>` element, put a span with a comma to separate it: `<td><span ng-repeat="id in todolist.id">{{id + ($last?'':', ')}}</span></td>`

Answer (score 0):

Your datas are not properly declared. It should be:

```
    $scope.todolists = [{
      date: '12/1/2016',
      list: [
        'python',
        'angularjs'
      ]
    }, {
      date: '13/1/2016',
      list: [
        'java',
        'html'
      ]
    }];
```

Note the '' around python, etc. and the list should be a list => [] and not {}.

A nice way to go is to write a custom filter:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .filter('nicelist', function() {
    return function(input) {
      if (input instanceof Array) {
        return input.join(",");
      }
      return input;
    }
  });
```

Then, you can use :

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="todolist in todolists">
    <td>{{todolist.date}}</td>
    <td>{{todolist.list | nicelist}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/3q7ynfjb/).

Comment: thank for providing your answer, I tried but it is not working properly. have a look at demo http://jsfiddle.net/mhenmqcg/6/  Here Last row is shift. I updated question please see it.

Comment: I am fixing it (there is a mispell in the code a pasted). And your ids are not arrays, which was in your question.

Comment: Many errors in your code. Seems like you tried to mix my solution with the other ones. Here is a fixed version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Shitsu/mhenmqcg/8/. Tell me if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `JSON` is invalid. If you want to store values without properties, you need to use `Array` but not `Object`. Also, if the values are `string` you need to wrap them with comma like: `['val1', 'val2', ...];`
2. You can do `ng-repeat` inside `ng-repeat` but you need to iterate the right property `todolist.list`.
3. You can't use `{{subject}}` if you have not property `subject` in you model. So you need to use `{{list}}` when you do the `ng-repeat` like `ng-repeat="list in todolist.list"`.

**The full code:**

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.todolists = [{ date: '12/1/2016', list: ['python', 'angularjs'] }, { date: '13/1/2016', list: ['java', 'html'] }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="todolist in todolists">
      <td>{{todolist.date}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="list in todolist.list">{{list}}</td>   
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Will work, but you forgot the commas between the values of the list.

Comment: I don't think that I forgot.. but I replaced now from ` to `'`.

Comment: @MoshFeu thank for providing your answer, I tried your example but it is not working properly. have a look at demo http://jsfiddle.net/mhenmqcg/6/  Here Last row is shift. I updated question please see it.

Comment: The code works perfectly.. The problem is that you try to generate multiple cells per id and the number of `id`s is different in each todolist. What do you want to do? To show them in one cell?